# montouch detect when sound finished playing

Tags: xamarin.ios

In objective C is a method called AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion which allows to add a handler for "audio done notification".
So I add the handler call AudioServicesPlaySystemSound and when the sound finished I'll get a notification.
monotouch has MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.SystemSound.PlaySystemSound to play such a sound.
But how do I know when the playing finished?

Situiation: I have a class which get's some information. When this information indicates an error I play a sound. If I'm already palying a sound I should do nothing.

And depending on a setting ("repeat alert") I should play the sound again the replay finished and the alert is still valid.

Sounds not so complicated - but without knowing when the sound finished playing I have a problem. So I can neither detect that I already play - nor can I repeat if needed.

Comment: If you use, AVAudioPlayer, it has something called "FinishedPlaying" where you can do something when the audio finishes playing.  But that's not a System Sound.  Do you need a System Sound?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't bound in MonoTouch yet, you should file an enhancement request at http://monotouch.net/Support so we can expose it properly.